# jQuery closest with attribute filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does jQuery 1.5.1 support attribute selectors in the closest method?

Given the structure below, `el` represents the checkbox with the value 513, and I'm trying to reach up and check the ancestor checkbox with the value of 0 with

```
$(el).closest("input[value='0']")[0].checked = true;
```

but the selector is returning nothing.

Am I missing something silly?

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Sigh, so the checkbox with value 0 isn't an ancestor to `el`, just a sibling of the `ul` ancestor.  I got it to work with

```
$(el).closest("ul").siblings("input[value='0']")[0].checked = true;
```

But us there a cleaner way to grab it?

Comment: WOW, I can't believe you are asking a question with the tags `jQuery` and `javascript`...

Comment: Aren't you the Javascript- jquery master here?

Comment: LOL - master?!  Not at all.  I'm decent, but there are many, many people here more knowledgeable than I am :)

Comment: So i guess that gold badge of javascript you have is a mistake... You're a humble man..

Comment: @gdoron - remember, rep and badges are, to a large degree, the amount of trust the community has in you, and the level of your addiction to Stack Overflow :) I know a decent amount about JavaScript and jQuery, and this was a silly mistake on a Saturday night, but there are many people who know more than me but have lower reputations. am not i am comes to mind as a good example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) *does* support attribute selectors the same as any other jQuery method (although I don't know about the specific version of jQuery you mentioned), but the problem here is that `.closest()` doesn't just look in the general vicinity, it goes up through the ancestors. You are trying to select an input element that is *not* an ancestor of the element you are starting with. (Given that inputs can't contain other elements they will *never* be the ancestors of anything...)

You should be able to do it by selecting the target checkbox's parent li element first:

```
$(el).closest('li:has(input[value="0"])')
     .find('input[value="0"]').prop("checked",true);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vpzyj/

Of course if you were able to add a class to the top level menu items you wouldn't  need to mess around with ":has", you could just say:

```
$(el).closest('li.topMenu').find('input[value="0"]').prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but I can't use prop since I'm on jQuery 1.5.  Can you think of a better way than my edit by chance?

Comment: Well as per my edit I'd give the top level li a class and select that, but really your edit (which I hadn't seen at the time) is better since it doesn't need to change the markup. The `.prop()` part is not really the key part of my answer, and I'm sure you know you can use `.attr("checked","checked")` or of course stick with `[0].checked = true` if you are sure there will always be a matching element. I forgot to set the right jQuery version in my demo, but here's an update where it works with 1.4.4: http://jsfiddle.net/Vpzyj/2/

Comment: Thanks - you didn't have to cook up a fiddle for me :)

Comment: You're welcome. Actually when I first answered the question I didn't really pay attention to who was asking it - if I'd actually noticed your name I would've known you'd understand perfectly without a fiddle. (Now that I know it's you, as per gdoron's comments above I'm a bit surprised...)

Comment: Yeah - maybe I shouldn't be working on a Saturday night when there are so many distractions :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check for: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
.closest( selector ) // version added: 1.3
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you shouldn't need the [0] as .closest only returns the first element found unlike parents() which returns multiple.

```
$(el).closest("input[value='0']").prop("checked") = true;
```

is the way I would prefer to do it.

This is assuming you are trying to check the "value 0" checkbox when you check the check the 513 box.

Edit: Sorry, misread this. In reality you need to try and get the <\li> tag and then get the underlying checkbox. Where you are actually looking for the checkbox which is not a direct parent.

Edit 2: You realize your edit doesn't work right? Wait... it would... you used siblings not children my mistake.

Edit 3: How about using:

```
$(el).parents().get(':eq(2)').children(':first-child');
```

or are we not assuming the layout is fixed?

Comment: I need the [0] since I'm checking the checked property on the underlying dom element

Answer (score 1):

Closest checks [**up** the DOM tree](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and not on the same level.

Comment: I realized that shortly after posting, and patiently waited for the flood of answers telling me so :)

Comment: @AdamRackis hehe it happens :-)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question: yes, it does (http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Your code does not work because closest() goes up through the DOM tree and in your case it would have to go up and and down because your checkbox 0 is not an ancestor of checkbox 513.