# How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?

Tags: jquery, events, onclick

I have a DIV with a classed `foobar`, and a few DIVs inside that DIV that are unclassed, but I suppose they are inheriting the `foobar` class:

```
$('.foobar').on('click', function() { /*...do stuff...*/ });
```

I want that to fire off only when clicking somewhere in the DIV but not on its children DIVs.

Answer (score 522, accepted):

If the `e.target` is the same element as `this`, you've not clicked on a descendant.

```js
$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  
  alert( 'clicked the foobar' );
});
```

```css
.foobar {
  padding: 20px; background: yellow;
}
span {
  background: blue; color: white; padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='foobar'> .foobar (alert) 
  <span>child (no alert)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That answer explains [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146163/jquery-closest-with-attribute-filter#comment11499568_9146163) comment

Comment: @gdoron: Adam is being too kind. :)

Comment: can you please answer my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9193293/601179)... =)

Comment: just removed an extra = in the if condition.

Comment: Hi @vicky. Just FYI, JavaScript has two different kinds of value equality comparison. The `===` or `!==` uses the *"Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm"*, while the `==` and `!=` uses the *"Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm"*, which is type coercive. The general wisdom is to always use *strict* comparison unless there's specific need for the coercive type *(since its rules are a little complex)*. In this case, because objects are being compared, it really doesn't make a difference, but you'll find that most people will still stick with the *strict* comparison.

Comment: ohhh really. I didnt knew this. Sorry it was a mistake then.

Comment: @vicky: That's alright. It's still correct. Just letting you JS has the different operators. ;-)

Comment: your code was having a problem you should write alert function first. Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaVzx/550/). :)

Comment: @GauravAggarwal: The purpose of having the `if` statement first is to make it so that the code below it does not run when clicking on children of the `.foobar` element. If we put the alert on top, it will always run. So basically, you should see the alert when clicking on the outer yellow area, but not on the blue child.

Comment: This is a good answer because it can also work with Vanilla JS addEventListener and is not jQuery specific.

Comment: In ReactJs, you would attach a reference to the parent div like <div ref={div => this.ref_name = div}></div>, and you would compare e.target with this.ref_name instead of with this

Comment: this accepted answer is not always correct due to the context of `this`... `this` could be pointing to something completely different than what you are expecting... Jens Törnell's answer below should be the correct answer.

Comment: how to do this on vanilla js?

Answer (score 128):

I did not get the accepted answer to work, but this seems to do the trick, at least in vanilla JS.

```
if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
```

Comment: e.currentTarget is more accurate than referencing `this` because the object that `this` is pointing to can change depending on the scope and context from where it is called

Comment: `event.currentTarget` looks to be the cleanest method here.

Comment: note that you can also do
`if (e.target === e.currentTarget) { ...your code }`
why this works: 
    e.target is the element that triggered the event (e.g., the user clicked on) 
    e.currentTarget is the element that the event listener is attached to.

so when you compare these two the element which the event is attached is same as the one was clicked.

Comment: Thanks the solution works perfectly for my problem. I observed is that when you log "e" and open the logged object currentTarget is null but when you log "e.currentTarget" it logs the element correctly. I am confused why?

Comment: Got my answer "Because the e.currentTarget property of the event object changes while propagating".

Comment: best answer for sure

Answer (score 111):

There's another way that works if you don't mind only targeting newer browsers. Just add the CSS

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to any children of the div you want to capture the click. Here's the support tables

http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Know that I should avoid writing 'thanks' comments, but I can kiss you foot for this :-)

Comment: @SimonaAdriani huh?

Comment: Thanks, I did the same way, but I'm struggling to write unit test case around it. How can I make sure `click` programatic click event trigger should be blocked?

Comment: This is not correct. You may still want to allow events on the child element, just not the parent element. For example, the parent might have a mouseover event, which you don't want on the child element that is an input, but obviously you want to use the input.

Comment: @Cybernetic - In that case you can just handle the click (or focus) event on the parent and then focus the input with `input.focus()`, but in any case there's multiple solutions to this problem and which one someone uses will be based on their use case anyway.

Answer (score 37):

You can use bubbling in your favor:

```
$('.foobar').on('click', function(e) {
    // do your thing.
}).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    // clicked on descendant div
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution for my specific scenario, as I only want to exclude clicks on descendant `<a>` elements. There is just one problem: When I middle click on them the event still triggers (tested in Google Chrome). Is there a variant of this that also prevents this?

Comment: @cgogolin, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197122/how-can-i-prevent-a-user-from-middle-clicking-a-link-with-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 23):

```
//bind `click` event handler to the `.foobar` element(s) to do work,
//then find the children of all the `.foobar` element(s)
//and bind a `click` event handler to them that stops the propagation of the event
$('.foobar').on('click', function () { ... }).children().on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    //you can also use `return false;` which is the same as `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` all in one (in a jQuery event handler)
});
```

This will stop the propagation (bubbling) of the `click` event on any of the children element(s) of the `.foobar` element(s) so the event won't reach the `.foobar` element(s) to fire their event handler(s).

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bQQJP/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and came up with this solution (based on the other answers)

```
 $( ".newsletter_background" ).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(".newsletter_background").hide();
    } 
});
```

Basically it says if the target is the div then run the code otherwise do nothing (don't hide it)

Comment: Can you use an arrow function here instead of `(function(e) {})`?

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".advanced ul li").live('click',function(e){
    if(e.target != this) return;
    //code
    // this code will execute only when you click to li and not to a child
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use event.currentTarget. It will do click event only elemnt who got event.

```js
target = e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
  };
```

```html
<ul onClick={target} className="folder">
      <li>
        <p>
          <i className="fas fa-folder" />
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: `currentTarget` doesn't decide if the event is executed. It just holds the reference to the element.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `pointer-events: none;` and are targeting modern browsers you can use `composedPath` to detect a direct click on the object like so:

```
element.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
    if (ev.composedPath()[0] === this) {
        // your code here ...
    }
})
```

You can read more about composedPath here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath

Answer (score 2):

When you define an event, the event has a property `this`. This property represents the DOMElement to which the event was assigned.To check the element in which the event was fired, use `e.target`.

Since events are inherited in the children of an element, check if the target

```js
function doSomething(event) {
  if (this == event.target){
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My case is similar but this is occasion when you have few `foobar`-s, and you want to close only one - per one click:

#### Find parent case

```
$(".foobar-close-button-class").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parents('.foobar').fadeOut( 100 );
    // 'this' - means that you finding some parent class from '.foobar-close-button-class'
    // '.parents' -means that you finding parent class with name '.foobar'
});
```

#### Find child case

```
$(".foobar-close-button-class").on("click", function () {
    $(this).child('.foobar-close-button-child-class').fadeOut( 100 );
    // 'this' - means that you finding some child class from '.foobar-close-button-class'
    // '.child' -means that you finding child class with name '.foobar-close-button-child-class'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// if its li get value 
document.getElementById('li').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                if (e.target == this) {
                    UodateNote(e.target.id);
                }
                })
                
                
                function UodateNote(e) {

    let nt_id = document.createElement("div");
    // append container to duc.
    document.body.appendChild(nt_id);
    nt_id.id = "hi";
    // get conatiner value . 
    nt_id.innerHTML = e;
    // body...
    console.log(e);

}
```

```css
li{
 cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 380px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: silver;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0.5cm;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 12%;}
    
    p{
     cursor: text;
  font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    max-width: 370px;
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow-x: hidden;}
```

```html
<li id="li"><p>hi</p></li>
```