# Efficient way to find elements not contained in another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

What's the most efficient way to find elements matching a selector which aren't inside *a given DOM node* (i.e I'm passed the node and can't necessarily deduce a selector to match it). So far I have

```
var inputs = $("input").filter(function() {
    return !$(excludedNode).has(this).length;
});
```

But can't help thinking there could be a better solution than this as, despite not being very much code, I doubt it's very efficient.

Comment: What about `$('#foo:not(:has(.bar))')`?

Comment: @Blender - I am passed the DOM node, not an id for the DOM node,so can't use a pure selector approach

Comment: @wheresrhys you can if the node *has* an "id" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up [a jsperf](http://jsperf.com/efficient-way-to-find-elements-not-contained-in-another/2) to test the valid suggestions other people made and one more idea.

Surprsingly, the method using `$.has` is about 3 times faster than using `$.closest`  (as it delegates to the browser's `document.element.contains`, whereas `$.closest` does some selector manipulation and traverses the DOM tree). It's also faster than `$("div").not("#" + id + " *")` by about the same difference.

So the fastest method is

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return !$(excludedNode).has(this).length;
});
```

and using `$.closest`, which intuitively felt like the fastest way, is actually the slowest

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
var inputs = $("input").filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest(excludedNode).length == 0
    //or:
    return !$(this).closest(excludedNode).length
});
```

It finds the elements you want, and then check if it has a parent of `excludedNode`

Comment: I think you can skip the ``== 0`` since it will return "falsy" if length is 0.

Comment: +1 @David. You are right, I added it to clarify the code, I wanted to add a comment about it, so thanks for doing it for me... **But you will need to add `!` in the beginning.**

Comment: Yeah, that would work. I'm gonna have  read of the jQUery source to work out which method looks most efficient. Your method probably iterates the parentNode properties whereas mine... I haven't a clue how `has` works. It may well be something like `$.fn.has = function(el) {return $.fn.closest.apply(el,this)}`, i.e. just a back to front `closest` call

Comment: @wheresrhys. You can test it with `jsperf`. Just be aware it will be probably a tiny micro optimization. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193293/does-too-many-ids-hurt-performace) question and the article linked in the accepted answer.

Comment: @gdoron, probably right. I'm really hoping to find some clever way of getting `DOM - excludedNode` and then running my selector with this as the 'context', rather than getting all elements and then running a check for each individually. Wishful thinking maybe.

Comment: @gdoron. Got around to setting up a jsperf and very surprisingly the method using $.has is twice as fast http://jsperf.com/efficient-way-to-find-elements-not-contained-in-another. Now I really do need to read the jQUery source to find out why this is true. Very counterintuitive

Comment: $.has more or less just calls $.contains, which in turn (via sizzle) uses document.element.contains, so uses quick native browser functionality. $.closest, on the other hand does a lot of selector processing before running a while loop over parent nodes

Comment: @wheresrhys. Thanks for the update. post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If the "excluded node" has an "id" or something to use as a selector, there's:

```
var inputs = $('input').not('#excluded *');
```

or

```
var inputs = $('input').not('#' + node.id + ' *');
```

Comment: +1 this eventually led to a general solution a lot faster than anything else

Comment: but I later realised it had a flaw and removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').not('#someID input').doSOmething()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = $('input').not('*', excludedNode);
```

or

```
var inputs = $('input').not('*', $(excludedNode));
```

that looks better.