# How can I prevent a user from middle clicking a link with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent the user from being able to middle click a certain link to open a new tab. I have tried the following:

```
$(window).on('mouseup', '.sptDetails', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.button == 1){
        return false;
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: pro tip: don't mess with default browser behavior - it will drive users away.

Comment: Also, middle-click isn't the only way to open a new tab...

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There are many ways to open a link in a new tab, and you cannot prevent all of them.

Comment: You will prevent users for opening tabs _at all_ if you mess with their experience.

Comment: Users will hate you and will stop using your website if you do this.

Comment: What if the user holding CTRL and click the link? :)

Comment: This is for an internal website for which there are about 25 users. The reason I want this is because I want the link to open in a modal dialog box using ajax. I capture the click event in order to trigger this but it doesn't work with middle click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an unfortunate combination of jQuery and the browser. To prevent the new tab from opening you have to use the `click` event (rather than `mouseup`), but jQuery [does not run delegate click handlers for mouse buttons other than the left one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L382):

```
// Avoid non-left-click bubbling in Firefox (#3861)
if ( delegateCount && !(event.button && event.type === "click") ) {
```

What you can do is using a non-delegate handler and check the target element yourself:  http://jsbin.com/ojoqap/10/edit. This works on Chrome, at least (inspired by @Abraham).

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is("a[href]") && e.button === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: @Mike: Please make sure to test it; apparently jQuery prevents the intuitive way due to some Firefox bug.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, this is a bad idea. I **do not** recommend doing this. See the comments above. But here's how to detect middle-click:

```
if (e.which == 2)
  return false
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` would be more appropriate because `return false` does `e.stopPropagation()` as well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I _think_ the problem here is that in your demo, you're trying to prevent a default on the `document`. I think since the event has already bubbled past the `a`, you can't prevent default.

Comment: That may be the case but it does work with e.g. preventing focus like here: http://jsbin.com/ojoqap/7/.

Comment: That theory sounds good to me. The problem is the links may be loaded dynamically so thats why I am doing it this way. Any ideas on how to bind to dynamically generated link and still be able to prevent the middle click?

Comment: Weird... let me do some testing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to make sure that some navigation remains in your 'parent' page. 
I think approaching this from another angle might be appropriate.

Assuming you don't need to worry about non-JS users, as an alternative to preventing a middle click, I might suggest loading the content via an ajax call and inserting it into your current page.

This could be accomplished with a little javascript while leaving it usable (though maybe not ideally by users with JS turned off)

Just something to think about. There's plenty of ways to improve upon this idea I'm sure.

HTML:

```
<a href="/mylink" id="href-load-content">
<div id="content-pane"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

     $('#href-load-content').data('href', function() { return $(this).attr('href') } )
        .attr('href', 'javascript:return;')
        .on('click', function() {
            $.get($(this).data('href'), function(msg) { $('#content-pane').html(msg); });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi go through this reference..

http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm

middle mouse keycode is 4

so you can try like this

```
if(e.which==4|| e.keycode==4)
e.returnValue=false;
```

Comment: Note that if you're getting your click events through jquery, you need to look up the `e.originalEvent.keyCode`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// <a href="http://google.com" id="google">Google</a><br> <a href="http://bing.com" id="bing">Bing</a>
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click", function(e){
    if($(e.target).is("#google") && e.button===1)
      e.preventDefault()
  })
})
```

[FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/kezcrxop/1/)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/auxclick_event) the `auxclick` event is the proper way to do this.

The following code will prevent the middle click behaviour on the entire page.

```
window.addEventListener("auxclick", (event) => {
  if (event.button === 1) event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want to disable it for a certain link only, just replace the event listener target (window) with a reference to the specific node.