# Apply onChange effect on a select option

Tags: reactjs

I have a DatePicker that has todayButton = Vandaag shown in the code and image below. I wanted to see if I can activate the todayButton by clicking on any of my select option instead of clicking Vandaag. I need some idea where to start. I appreciate any insight on this.

````
```<div className="status">
<select name="status" id="status">
<option selected>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select></div>```


```DatePicker
  todayButton="Vandaag"
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
/>```
````

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but from what i understand you want to change the date to today's date from the select. Instead of going in a round about manner of selecting today button  you can update startDate using setStartTime when you select corresponding option in select.

```
const onSelectChange = (e) => {
 if (e.target.value === "Today") {
    setStartDate(new Date())
 }
}
```

Comment: Its not working, it doesn't change the date in the datepicker to today. I don't know what I'm missing I tried different approach similar to that one but It never  taken effect to the date picker date.

Comment: Did you check if the state is update properly. Console log startDate and see if the update is happening due to the select option change

Comment: <DatePicker
      todayButton="Vandaag"
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
    />

Comment: <div className="status"><select name="status" id="status"> 
   <option selected >Submitted</option>
   <option>First Interview</option>
   <option>Additional Interview</option>
   <option>Final Interview</option>
   <option>Offer</option>
   <option>Placement</option>
   <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
   <option>No Update</option>
   </select></div>

Comment: I am trying to see I I can apply this one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662734/click-on-an-element-triggers-the-click-on-another-element-jquery