# Mouse-up event goes wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here my code:

```
<div class="container" role="main">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showAssignLabelsInMain(this);">Assign Labels</a></li>
    <div class="labelListInMain" id="labelListInMain">
        <g:render template=""/>
    </div>
</div>

function showAssignLabelsInMain(elm) {
        $.ajax({type: 'POST',
            url: '${createLink(controller: "HRAdmin", action: "labelListInMain")}',
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $('#labelListInMain').html(data);
            }
        });
        var offset = $(elm).offset();
        $("#labelListInMain").css({top: offset.top + 25, left: offset.left - 18, position: 'absolute'});
        $('#labelListInMain').toggle('fast');

$(".container").mouseup(function (e) {
        var subject = $("#labelListInMain");
        alert(e.target.id)

        if (e.target.id != subject.attr('id')) {
            subject.fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

It means that when I clicked the button, toggle will show up, but when I click inside that toggle, it fades out. It is not supposed to fade out and I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: you forgot to add EOS(end of statement) in your `alert(e.target.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".link").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(".popup").fadeIn(300,function(){$(this).focus();});
});

$('.close').click(function() {
 $(".popup").fadeOut(300);
});
$(".popup").on('blur',function(){
 $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LxauG/10/)

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks guys +1 for demo!

Comment: Excuse me bro, Can I ask a question? $(".popup").on('blur',function(){ means that when pop u opened, click mouse inside that, blur even will not happened right? Cause I tried it on my project and when I clicked in pop up, it faded out.

Comment: Please share your HTML or create Fiddle demo.

Comment: Here my code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/5xVg9/), I applied your code but it's not work on my project.

Comment: Hey i have checked you Demo but it contains only your javascript part not HTML and javascript code is not mine it your which is asked in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do from another method

```
$(".container").click(function (e) {
    var subject = $("#labelListInMain");

    if (!$(e.target).closest('.labelListInMain').length) {
        subject.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, it fades out while popup open !

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be connected to something like this

[How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children)

you want the div to fade when the .container is clicked but not if it was toggle that was clicked right?
and toggle is a child of .container
try looking this up too
http://api.jquery.com/children/