# table row click event and checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have a click event attached to a table row and within columns i have checkboxes.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='shop_order_single_table'>
            <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When i click the checkbox the click event for the row still executes.

Here is my code:

```
     $(".shop_order_single_table").on("click",function() {
   //click event executes
                });
```

How do i have the click event for the table row not execute when clicking a checkbox?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".shop_order_single_table input").on("click", function(e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
});   

$(".shop_order_single_table").on("click", function(e) { 
   // Your code
});
```

Comment: I tried this and the click event is still executed?

Comment: Thanks, updated code works!

Comment: @user892134 always welcome!