# Hide a div on click but do nothing when click on image which is inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div `main-wrap` and an image in it.

I want to hide `main-wrap` when click on it. But when you click on image that is inside main-wrap I don't want to do anything. Right now I have this non-working code. When I click on image main-wrap still hides. (hidden is my class `.hidden {display:none}`)

```
<div class="main-wrap" >
    <div class="photo-wrap">
        <img style="cursor:default;"  onclick = "return false;" class="img img-responsive" src = "/stat_photo/1.jpg"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

And I have this code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.main-wrap').click(function(){$('.main-wrap').addClass('hidden')});
 });
```

Comment: Hey, it seems like .main-wrap is missing from your code. I guess it goes above .photo-wrap?

Comment: you have added photo-wrap here, is this the original html what you are using!!

Comment: yeah sorry guys. it's above photo-wrap

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children

Comment: @Gothdo `$('.main-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
     if (e.target !== this){
      return;
     }
     $('.main-wrap').addClass('hidden');
    }); `  I tried this but it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this code

```
$('.main-wrap').on('click', function(e) {
                    $('.main-wrap').addClass('hidden');
                }).on('click', 'img', function(e) {
                    // clicked on descendant div
                    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

which is taken from here
[How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children)
(the accepted answer didn't work though)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.main-wrap').click(function(e) {
   $(this).addClass('hidden');
}).on('click', 'img', function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfwsqxko/1/

I added a click event, which extends with an exceptional click on image, which is set to `return false;`

Answer (score -1):

Better add an id of the image. Then replace .img with #yourid

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.main-wrap').not('.img').click(function(){$('.main-wrap').addClass('hidden')});
        });
```