# Bind event only on the parent element

Tags: jquery

I have this html data:

```
<select class="select">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

How do I bind an event only when I click the `select` element shown in the page, not when the `option` elements are clicked. I don't want to bind event on the items that are in the dropdown.

Update:
I did found this one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children). But it does not work for my case.

Comment: try : $('select').focus(function(){...});
or
$('select').click(function(){...});

Comment: Thank you. I think the first option does the job but I'm not sure if it's good for long run..

Comment: Ok, I am putting this as an answer. Please mark it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job for now.

```
$('.select').on('focus', function() {
    //code here
});
```

But I'm not sure if it is good for long run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
$('select').on('focus',function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you are looking like this ?  @Rabin Lama

Comment: Better use `change` event

Comment: ya i given change option first..But he is telling on click of the select only want to trigger event

Comment: No. I didn't wanna bind the event while clicking on the list items (i.e. list item `a`)

Comment: when you focus on the select also the list out will get trigger and option get changed.May i know reason of asking like that?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
$('select').focus(function(){...});
```

or

```
$('select').click(function(){...});
```