# div with onclick inside another div click also firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I have parent div and inside child div's(many). Parent div had addEventListener with click event. But when i click the inside the child div that one also event firing. I want to stop those things.

Example I have A parent div, and B child div.
When i click A div only need to add some logic(get content in b div), when i click the B div don't do anything.

```js
var content= document.querySelector('.test-content');
    content.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      var check = this.querySelector('.testClass');
      alert("fired");
      evt = evt || window.event;
      stopPropagation(evt);    
    });
    
 function stopPropagation(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.stopPropagation == "function") {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="test-content" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:yellow" >This is Div A
<div style="width:20%;height:100px;background-color:red"> This is Div B
 <div class="testClass" > test</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children

Comment: The linked answer is not a true duplicate. That answer tells how to stop child events from firing entirely, this question is about how to stop both the child and parent events from firing when the child is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply check if `evt.target != this` before proceeding further.

**Demo**

```js
var content= document.querySelector('.test-content');
    content.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
      if ( evt.target != this ) return false; //notice this line
      alert("fired");
      evt = evt || window.event;
      stopPropagation(evt);    
    });
    
 function stopPropagation(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.stopPropagation == "function") {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="test-content" style="width:100%;height:200px;background-color:yellow" >This is Div A
<div style="width:20%;height:100px;background-color:red"> This is Div B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. It's working fine

Comment: Why answered it if you have marked it as duplicate?

Comment: @brk I was about to delete mine. I guess you wanted to ask *why answer if this is a duplicate* :)