# In Jquery, why children react to function for parent?

Tags: jquery

I would like the children to be hidden when parent is clicked again but not when children are clicked. For some reason children are treated as $level1 elements while I was expecting them not to respond to $level1.click function. I think I'm missing something trivial, but I can't help myself. Here you are the filddle https://jsfiddle.net/bxmbtzrb/3
Thank you for your suggestions.

The structure

```
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>PARENT</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">CHILD 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">CHILD 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">CHILD 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

The Jquery script:

```
var $level1 =$('nav').children('ul').children('li');
  $level1.click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
      $(this).removeClass('on');
    } else {
      $level1.filter('.on').removeClass('on');
      $(this).addClass('on');
    }
  });
    nav li:not(.on) li {
      display: none;
    }
```

and CSS:

```
nav li:not(.on) li {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your children are treated as '$level1' elements because of your jQuery selector : `var $level1 =$('nav').children('ul').children('li');` --> Your event is triggered on click on your selected 'li' AND all its childrens.

You can use tricks to check if it's the parent who fire the event ([How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children)), but I suggest you an other way to do what you want.

```
//You get your parent 'li' element
var list = $('nav').children('ul').children('li');
//You get your 'a' element, the one who have to fire the event
var $level1 = list.children('a');

//Init the event
$level1.click(function() {
    //Add or Remove the 'on' class of the parent list
    list.toggleClass('on');
});
```

You have your fiddle updated here : https://jsfiddle.net/bxmbtzrb/25/

Comment: Your answer gives a solution to my question, I guess, although the real case scenario having multiple parents this solution falls short. I think I'll give a look to the link you provide, it seems having what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: I updated the fiddle to make a version with multi parents :) https://jsfiddle.net/bxmbtzrb/32/

Comment: Exactly what I needed! It still not clear for me why the selector `var $level1 =$('nav').children('ul').children('li')`  addresses the 'li' AND all its children. Is that default behaviour?

Comment: The jQuery selector select only the 'li' element. But when you put the click event on the 'li', it applies to it's children too. Imagine you have a square with a text insine, you put the click event on the square. If you click on the text inside the square, you still click on the square too.

Answer (score 1):

your `$level1` selector, contains everything inside your first list, including the children, which is why the children also hide after being clicked.

I would recommend using an `id` on the parent and using that as a selector. If you can't do that then select the first child link:

```js
var $level1 =$('nav > ul > li > a:first-child');
var children =$('nav > ul > li');
$level1.click(function() {
  $(children).toggleClass('on');
});
```

```css
nav li:not(.on) li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>PARENT</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">CHILD 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">CHILD 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">CHILD 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```