# jQuery & CSS Selectors

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table row with one of the `td` containing a `button`. I want to be able to click the `tr` and have that trigger a function. However, I do not want this function to be triggered if the button within the `td` is clicked. My current method is by using a `:not` selector on the `td` of the button but i would prefer to use the button itself. The class `noclick` is the class of the `button` parent `td`.

```
$('#mytable td:not(.noclick)').on('click',function(){
```

EDIT: for clarification

```
<tr data-x="test">
  <td>NAme</td>
  <td>Phone</td>
  <td class="noclick"> // this is where the current not selector works
    <button>X</button> // this button is the only place I want the not selector to work
  </td>
</tr>
```

So to clarify I want a similar process to my posted handler but instead I want the buttons parent `td` to work for the click function and not work for the button itself.

I have tried a few different things including still using the `td` but trying to make the `td` a minimal size. I was not able to get the `td` to become smaller.

Comment: Did the above selector not work as you expected? Can you also add your html then we can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183467/12804871 it seems your case

Comment: @nathanielflick it works as expected but this is for the `td` as a whole, not the `button`

Comment: Is there something other than the button in the td that you want the click logic to happen for?

Comment: @taplar no I dont believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `e.target` equals `this` you clicked on the `td` element, not a descendant, such as `button`. In other words the click event is not due to event bubbling.

```js
$('#mytable td:not(.noclick)').on('click',function(e) {
    if(e.target !== this) return;
    console.log('Clicked!!!!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>col 1</td>
  <td>col 2</td>
  <td>col 3</td>
  <td>col 4<button class="noclick">No Click</button></td>
  <td>col 5</td>
</td>
<tr>
  <td>col 1</td>
  <td>col 2</td>
  <td>col 3</td>
  <td>col 4<button class="noclick">No Click</button></td>
  <td>col 5</td>
</td>
<tr>
  <td>col 1</td>
  <td>col 2</td>
  <td>col 3</td>
  <td>col 4<button class="noclick">No Click</button></td>
  <td>col 5</td>
</td>
<tr>
  <td>col 1</td>
  <td>col 2</td>
  <td>col 3</td>
  <td>col 4<button class="noclick">No Click</button></td>
  <td>col 5</td>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Reference**

- [event.target | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)
- [How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9183467/12804871)

Comment: Thank you for the working solution! I will accept it if you could just provide some explanation about whats going on in the background with `if(e.target !== this) return;`. More specifically what `e` and `e.target` will be. I can edit in the info if necessary.