# Why querySelectorAll select non-qualified child elements as well?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu.

I want to add event listener to elements with class "menu-item-has-children"(which should also be a descendant of element with class "mobile-nav")

So I use the following codes:

```
    function addEventListenerToAll(selector, type, listener)
    {
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(element) {
            if (element) {
                element.addEventListener(type, listener);
            }
        });
    }
    
        addEventListenerToAll(".mobile-nav .menu-item-has-children", "click", function(event) {
          
          console.log("click event is invoked");
    });
```

But it seems the code will add the listener to not only the qualified elements, but also the child elements inside the qualified elements.

I embed the codes below. You can see when click "Out customers" item, the child element but not qualified the selector, the "click event is invoked" will also appear. Why?

```js
function addEventListenerToAll(selector, type, listener)
{
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function(element) {
        if (element) {
            element.addEventListener(type, listener);
        }
    });
}
    
addEventListenerToAll(".mobile-nav .menu-item-has-children", "click", function(event) {
    console.log("click event is invoked");
});
```

```css
.mobile-nav .menu-item-has-children {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navigation mobile-nav" role="navigation" style="display: block;">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="sf-menu mobile-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1294" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1294">
            <a href="https://www.sybase-recovery.com/company/">
                Company
                <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10"><use href="/images/icons/icons.svg#facebook-f"></use></svg>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
                <li id="menu-item-433" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-433">
                    <a href="https://www.sybase-recovery.com/our-customers/">Our Customers</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: add `.mobile-nav .menu-item-has-children {
  background:green;
}` style - now you'll see the area your click handler handles

Comment: If you click on a child of an element with a click handler, have you clicked on the handler? I would say yes. It's like visiting LA. Have you also visited the US? Yes. This is just event bubbling.

Comment: @JaromandaX funnily enough, this exact snippet proves this is not the case. The `<li>`'s disc ::marker will also be a target to click events, but it's not part of the element's border-box. Similarly, if the element had a positioned descendant that would put it outside of the element, the events on that descendant would still bubble up **the DOM** until the `<li>`.

Comment: Many events like `click` are propagating. If you only want to handle events that happen on the element directly you need to check the event target, that the target where the event currently is at mtches the element where the event handler is attached at (`e.target !== e.currentTarget`): [How to have click event ONLY fire on parent DIV, not children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183381/how-to-have-click-event-only-fire-on-parent-div-not-children)

Comment: You need to delegate "click" events by creating conditions in which only the desired elements on the event chain react to a "click" event whilst the excluding the undesirable elements by ignoring then. It's best to use `event.target` to single out the clicked element and `.matches()` as the condition. Read about [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

Comment: @Kaiido - sure, but perhaps OP wasn't aware of how big the clickable area was

Answer (score 0):

In the JS user events topic, there is something called [bubbling and capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing). When you do a click on the *not-qualified* child of the element which actually is *listening* to the event, that action goes through all the DOM tree until reach the clicked element (capturing), triggering the event on its ancestors; and the same situation happens after that phase but on the other way (from the target element to the top of the DOM tree; that's called *bubbling*). If you print `this`, you will see that the actual element which is listening to the event is the one that you attached to the event through `addEventListener` method.

So, in order to avoid this issue and just affect the attached element, you must check if `this` is equal to the clicked element, which is represented by [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Only when both are the same, you print the message on console.

```js
if (this == event.target){
    console.log("click event is invoked");
}
```

Note that doing this, clicking on the links never shows the message in console. That's because you attached an `<li>` to the `click` event, not the links. So, if you want to show the message when user clicks on the links, just attach them to the event.

Comment: You can also use the [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property instead of `this`.

Comment: Which seems like the better solution, since the prevalent use of arrow functions these days makes the `this` a risky strategy to go for.